# Convert bipartite graph to monopartite for community detection with GDS library

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, bipartite

I'm trying to register a graph using `gds.graph.create`. The source graph contains two node classes connected by one relationship type. I would like the in-memory graph to have only a single node type so I can perform community detection. Here is what I have so far:

```
CALL gds.graph.create(
'userDataMono',
'MATCH (a) WHERE a:User OR a:Dataset RETURN id(a) as id',
'MATCH (a:User)-[r:GRANTED_ACCESS]-(b:Dataset) RETURN id(a) as from, id(b) as to'
)
YIELD  graphName AS graph, nodeProjection, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipCount AS rels
```

If I run the node query by itself, I get the expected list of node id's for both classes but if I run the full query as written above I get:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.create`: Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid node projection, one or more labels not 
found: 'MATCH (a) WHERE a:User OR a:Dataset RETURN id(a) as id'
```

How do I correctly register this graph for analysis?

`Neo4j 4.3.5` and `GDS Library 1.7.1`

Answer (score 0):

You are using native projection procedure and are using Cypher Projection syntax.

You could use native Projection syntax as following:

```
CALL gds.graph.create(
'userDataMono',
['User', 'Dataset'],
'GRANTED_ACCESS'
)
YIELD  graphName AS graph, nodeProjection, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipCount AS rels
```